# Use the same route with different types of users

Tags: express, server, roles

I'm developing an Expressjs application and I want to know how I could access the same route using different types of users.

In my application, I'm using sessions to authenticate the user, so when the user is logged in, I store the user id in a session on the server. When the user sends a request to the server I use that id to access the user data, my question is the following, how an admin user can use these same routes to access the user data?. In the case of an admin, I can't use the id stored in the session, because the admin id and the user id are different. One solution would be to send the user id in the params of the request, but then I have another problem, how can I know when to use the id of the params or the id of the session.

For example I have the route GET `/user`, this route return the logged in user, using the session id:

```js
route.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  const user = User.findOne(req.session.userId);
  res.json(user)
})
```

But what happend if I'am a admin and I want get a user by his id, I need to duplicate the route, but instead of use the session id I use the id send in the params:

```js
route.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  const user = User.findOne(req.params.userId);
  res.json(user)
})
```

Now, imagine that these routes are much bigger and have dozens of lines. I wouldn't like to repeat the same logic several times.

I don't want that a normal user can access to his data using its id (as a param in the URL), because that user just must access his own data and if I put the id in the URL then a logged in user could access the data of other users.

What I want to achieve is that the normal user just can access their own data, but that the admin users can access the data of all users, without having to create different routes for each type of user.

I want to know as this scenario is managed on other applications.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to save the user's role in session then use a middleware to check his privilege.

middlewares/Auth.js

```
exports.hasPrivilege = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.isAdmin) {
    return next();
  }
  res.status(403).json({
   msg: 'Forbidden'
  });
};
```

If the user is allowed to access this route the function will send the data

```
route.get('/user/:id', Auth.hasPrivilege, (req, res) => {
  const user = User.findOne(req.params.userId);
  res.json(user);
});
```